# How to find top-k accuracy for SVM and Naive Bayes

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, naivebayes

Mine is a multi-class classification problem with 50 classes. I am attempting to find the top-k categorical accuracy for SVM and NB algorithms.

```
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(sentences, labels, test_size=0.3, random_state = 42)

nb = Pipeline([('vect', CountVectorizer(min_df=1, dtype=np.int32, vocabulary= vocab_data, ngram_range=(1, 2))),
           ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer(use_idf=False)),
           ('chi',  SelectKBest(chi2, k='all')),
           ('clf', OneVsRestClassifier(MultinomialNB(alpha=0.001))),
          ])

y_pred = nb.predict(X_test)

print('accuracy %s' % accuracy_score(y_pred, y_test))
```

I am able to find the accuracy precision and recall values. Is there a way to find top k accuracy?

Comment: have you tried `sklearn.metrics.top_k_accuracy_score`?

Answer (score 0):

```
probs = nb.predict_proba(X_test)
print('accuracy %s' % top_k_accuracy_score(y_test, probs, k=5))
```

This prints top k accuracy